# Tascam US-122L USB Audio Interface + jackd

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, sound, soundcard, external-soundcard

I'm trying to get a [Tascam US-122L USB 2.0 Audio/MIDI Interface](http://tascam.com/product/us-122l/) working with jackd.

The correct kernel modules seem to load when I plug the device in:

```
$ lsmod | grep us122l
snd_usb_us122l         23020  0 
snd_usbmidi_lib        29476  1 snd_usb_us122l
snd_hwdep              17709  2 snd_usb_us122l,snd_hda_codec
snd                    78957  18 snd_usb_us122l,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
```

ALSA seems to detect the card:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0x60000000 irq 16
 1 [US122L         ]: USB US-122L - TASCAM US-122L
                      TASCAM US-122L (644:800e if 0 at 001/004)
```

Also:

```
$ aplay -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=SB
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=SB,DEV=0
    HDA ATI SB, AD198x Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usb_stream:CARD=SB
    HDA ATI SB
usb_stream:CARD=US122L
    TASCAM US-122L
```

The card also shows up in `qjackctl`, but when I select it as interface and try to start jackd, I get the following error:

```
16:37:20.811 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: Starting jack server...
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: control device hw:1
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: control device hw:1
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: Acquired audio card Audio1
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: creating alsa driver ... hw:1|hw:1|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: control device hw:1
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: ERROR: ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: ERROR: JackServer::Open() failed with -1
Fri Jun 20 16:37:20 2014: ERROR: Failed to open server
Fri Jun 20 16:37:21 2014: Saving settings to "/home/kraxor/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
16:37:36.683 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Tried to modify `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `~/.asoundrc` according to the [answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309234/how-to-get-tascam-us-122l-sound-card-to-work), but it didn't solve the problem. Currently they look like this:

```
$ cat .asoundrc | grep -v \#
pcm.!usb_stream {
        @args [ CARD ]
        @args.CARD {
                type string
                default "1"
        }

        type usb_stream

        card $CARD
}

ctl.!usb_stream {
        @args [ CARD ]
        @args.CARD {
                type string
                default "1"
        }

        type hw

        card $CARD
}


$ cat /etc/security/limits.conf | grep -v \#
@audio   -   rtpio     99
@audio   -   memlock   unlimited
@audio   -   nice      -10
```

The same happens with Xubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu Studio 12.04.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. This card *should be* supported as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

- If Pulseaudio is running, you may have this problem.
  To stop it for testing, run 2 commands:
  `echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf`
  `pulseaudio -k`