# Ubuntu can be used as Hard Real time OS?

Tags: realtime

I want OS for Beagleboard which can support HARD REAL TIME OS Feature.
is Ubuntu HARD Real time OS ?

Answer (score 6):

No.

Ubuntu uses Linux, which is not a real time kernel. Although you might be able to start from an Ubuntu system and modify the kernel so that it does meet real time guarantees, I don't think it would be correct to say that Ubuntu is a real time OS.

See [How can I install a realtime kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/q/72964/7808) which is a related question on modifying Ubuntu to run a Linux kernel that has been modified to add real time features.