# Multiple kernels choices realtime or no realtime

Tags: laptop, jack, realtime

I have a dell latitude d510 currently running xubuntu 13.04 and linux 3.8. I want this machine to host JACK processes together with EDIROL UA-25 during a live session and therefore, it needs an RT kernel. Since this is a laptop, I do like to have no RT kernel installed also saving power. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be using a **lowlatency** kernel, which you could do by installing the appropriate meta package **linux-image-lowlatency**, respectively **linux-image-lowlatency-pae** for 32 bit systems.

With different kernels installed, grub will allow you to choose between the available kernels when booting. So you could use the lowlatency kernel for music sessions and a 'normal' one for power savings.

I recommend using the lowlatency kernel instead of a realtime kernel because there currently are no official packages for the latter – as per [this question here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72964/how-can-i-install-a-realtime-kernel?rq=1) – and thus even the Ubuntu Studio guys [recommend trying the lowlatency kernel first](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel).

Comment: So it will keep the other kernel and I will see two in GRUB?

Comment: Yeah, Ubuntu has no problems with keeping multiple kernels available. Obviously, you can only have one kernel running at a time, but there's nothing keeping you from having as many kernels installed as you want – apart from disk space, of course.

Comment: depends upon what you do in "live session" but probably don't need realtime. low-latency is usually enough. For overdubbing live to recorded tracks want low delay to keep things synchronised, but for recording a live session, set JACK for no x-runs - any delay in recording will be same for all sources