# How to patch rt kernel in ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, kernel, patch

I have followed the steps given in the below link...
[How can I install a realtime kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72964/how-can-i-install-a-realtime-kernel/83066#83066)
.......after installing the kernel, system is not rebooting automatically.
Need help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to your issue, but you may want to take this into consideration:

> Low-latency kernel
>
> As of Ubuntu Studio 12.04, the default kernel is linux-lowlatency,
>   which in essence is a generic Ubuntu Linux kernel, with a tweaked
>   configuration to allow for stable operation for audio applications at
>   lower latencies. **Since much of the real-time patch has now been
>   implemented into the vanilla kernel, and considering the difficulties
>   in maintaining linux-rt, Ubuntu Studio decided on using
>   linux-lowlatency in its place.**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Studio#Low-latency_kernel

Comment: Actually I need to submit project in modular programming, for which rt patch is must. Please anyone having exp. of rt patching.